# Apache htaccess RewriteCond and RewriteRule to return a 404 based on whitelist

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a whitelist of URIs that are accessible on my Wordpress site. Below, I have just `/golf` but I will need `/wp-admin` and a custom login page `/crmpicco-login` - something like `(golf|wp-admin|crmpicco-login)`?

My Wordpress `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    # if the request uri is not /golf
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/golf

    # response 404 error
    RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]

    # this works!
    #RewriteRule ^/?crmpicco$ - [R=404]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

When I try to access any page it gives me the error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /golf was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

This is what I see in my Apache log, so i'm assuming my `RewriteRule` is misconfigured:

> [Wed Jul 03 11:35:05.964404 2019] [core:error] [pid 9673] [client
>   127.0.0.1:53894] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use
>   'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use
>   'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

The commented out `RewriteRule` to serve a 404 works, but the `RewriteCond` followed by the `RewriteRule` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just try it in the RewriteRule only.

```
RewriteRule ^/?(golf|wp-admin|crmpicco-login)(/.*)?$ - [R=404]
```

Comment: It's actually a "not in this whitelist". I have tried this but it gives me the same error as above.`RewriteRule !^/?(golf|wp-admin)$ - [R=404]`. I do get a HTTP 404, but the error is `Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`. There's nothing in the Apache error log. Any ideas?

Comment: This works to the extent it will 404 for all these pages, but I want to invert the condition to 404 for any pages that don't start with golf, wp-admin or crmpicco-login.

Comment: Ok add the ! before the ^ have the redirect like this [R=404,L] and are you sure that you set the location correctly to your 404 error document? Also do you have any other redirects in your htaccess?